# Loading Script within Script within Array

Tags: javascript, php

Evening all hoping someone can help im getting errors on this can anyone point me in right direction?

```
// First 468x60 Space 
$ad_space_1 = array(
//AD3 - RTB System Ads 
'<div id="RTBDIV_12946">
    <div id="RTBPL_12946">
        <a href="//rtbsystem.com/en/advertiser/request">Add advertisement</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    if (document.getElementById(\'RTBDIV_12946\')) {
        var I12946SD = new Date();
        document.write(\'<scr'+'ipt async '
            +'src="//code.rtbsystem.com/12946.js?t='+I12946SD.getYear()+I12946SD.getMonth()
            +I12946SD.getDay()+I12946SD.getHours() + '" charset="utf-8" ></scr'+'ipt>\');
    }
</script>'
);
```

My guess is the '

Comment: just escape the ' in the string

Comment: forgot about that! thanks Musa! amended the code above!

Comment: Do you mind telling us what errors you are getting?

Comment: Its all solved now just didnt escape the strings like @Musa said :)

Comment: Consider using HEREDOC syntax rather than quotes for big multi-line strings like this, especially where the strings contain quote mark characters.